# Как убрать расстояния между блоками? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно убрать расстояние между блоками в Wordpress 5.9.3 ? (на скриншоте выделено красными кружками).

Как сейчас обстоят дела:

[image: Как сейчас обстоят дела]

Как нужно чтобы было:

[image: Как нужно чтобы было]

Хотелось бы решить проблему стандартными средствами wordpress. Буду благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А как у вас тема собрана в конструкторе или сами писали? Если в коснтрукторе - то идите в конструктор и там меняйте значения, если сами писали показывайте что писали.

Comment: @MaxWatson тема собрана в конструкторе. В конструкторе какие именно значения? По факту, между блоками ничего нет, также если указываю расстояние между блоками 0px, либо отрицательное значение - ничего не меняется и остается все также с расстояними между блоками. прикреплю на всякий случай ссылку: https://ovenmedia.shishataganka.ru

Comment: Это можно поменять в файле theme.json Вашей темы, Вам нужно изменить значение `blockGap`, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @simon вроде бы помогло, но также поехала часть верстки, в частности блок ссылок. https://i.ibb.co/dML81dC/2022-04-14-19-16-53.png, может быть можно как-то эти блоки вывести в отдельную группу?

Comment: Все-таки, пришел к тому, что реализовать косые линии границ нужно при помощи :before :after с transform. Подскажите, как это сделать применительно к моему примеру?